# Why is garbage value being assigned to an already declared variable in the code below?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, garbage

This is a bit of a complicated problem to describe and it's been extremely frustrating to debug. This is for an assignment i'm working on, so please don't exactly fix my code but perhaps provide some guidance.

I'm creating an array of *card_t pointers, then feed through input redirection a series of data which are credit cards, these have: an encrypted card ID (8 char), a daily limit and transaction limit. The %%%%%% to signify the end of the input. The input are sorted alphabetically.

The inputs would look something like:

```
2uu2iywy 7000 120
op81hs12 1000 50
zh8102ol 4300 90
%%%%%%%%
```

The struct i use looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char id[ID_LENGTH + 1];
    int daily_limit;
    int transaction_limit;
} card_t;
```

Stage_one of the code:

Allocates memory for the first struct pointer, then we read the first line of input.

```
/*reads one card, puts into appropriate struct attribute
    return 1 if read successfully, 0 if reached % split*/
int read_one_card(card_t *one_card) {
    int x, i = 0;
    while(((x = getchar()) != EOF) && (x != ' ')) {
        if(x == '%') return 0;
        if(x != 10) {
            one_card->id[i++] = x;
        }
    }
    one_card->id[i] = '\0';
    scanf("%d", &one_card->daily_limit);
    scanf("%d", &one_card->transaction_limit);

    return 1;
}

void stage_one(card_t **accounts) {

    *accounts = (card_t*)malloc(sizeof(card_t)); //Allocate memory for one account

    read_one_card(*accounts);

    print_header(1);

    printf("Card ID: %s\n", accounts[0]->id);
    printf("Daily limit: %d\n", accounts[0]->daily_limit);
    printf("Transaction limit: %d\n", accounts[0]->transaction_limit);
}
```

Stage 2 does the same but will read everything up to the %%%%%% separator, this is when it gets extremely weird. For example, using sample input (outputs are at the end of the post):

```
3tu2iywy 10000 800
ceww0p66 150 100
v0xyil5t 3000 500
vb3dtxp0 5000 300
xnwxw8tl 2000 800
%%%%%%%%%%
```

Everything prints out as expected except the last 2 iterations, hence for the last line of input and when i assign NULL to the final pointer to indicate the read has terminated. The output for accounts[0]->id becomes some random value.

```
void stage_two(card_t **accounts) {
    int i = 1, is_card;
    while(1) {
        accounts[i] = (card_t*)malloc(sizeof(card_t)); 
/*I noticed here, after the above line is run, accounts[0] gets reassign to some garbage value*/
        printf("accounts[0]->id : %s\n", accounts[0]->id);
        if(!read_one_card(accounts[i])){
            accounts[i] = NULL;
            break;
        } 
        i++;
    };
}
```

What makes it so frustrating thought is that if use this as input:

```
ceww0p66 150 100
deww0p11 100 100
eeww0p22 105 101
%%%%%%%%%%
```

it works perfectly fine, so i'm completely confused at this point. I thought perhaps is because the time i get wrong output is due to having a number as the first char, but that really shouldn't be a problem, since after change the '3' to a random letter, i still get the problem. I tried with removing the first line, problem still occurs, first struct pointer gets altered somehow. Then i tired adding the "3tu2iywy" into the second set of input as first line, the problem then occurs again.

Here's the output, after calling a function that prints every attribute of each struct in the array.

```
Card ID: ｰﾅ
Daily limit: 0
Transaction limit: 800
==============================
Card ID: ceww0p66
Daily limit: 150
Transaction limit: 100
==============================
Card ID: v0xyil5t
Daily limit: 3000
Transaction limit: 500
==============================
Card ID: vb3dtxp0
Daily limit: 5000
Transaction limit: 300
==============================
Card ID: xnwxw8tl
Daily limit: 2000
Transaction limit: 800
==============================
```

CARD ID for the first output is always something different, also Daily Limit sometimes become 0, sometimes doesn't. The error is really random, which makes it so frustrating. Using the second set of inputs i get what is expected:

```
Card ID: ceww0p66
Daily limit: 150
Transaction limit: 100
==============================
Card ID: deww0p11
Daily limit: 100
Transaction limit: 100
==============================
Card ID: eeww0p22
Daily limit: 105
Transaction limit: 101
==============================
```

Comment: Why don't you use `scanf("%s")` to read the first word of each line, instead of writing your own `getchar()` loop?

Comment: Show how you're calling `stage_two()`. I suspect the problem is with the way you allocatred the array that you pass as the argument.

Comment: Also, array indexes start at 0, why do you initialize `i = 1`?

Comment: There's not enough here to see what you might be doing wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run *as is* to get the same results as you.

Comment: You also have a memory leak. When `read_one_card()` returns `0`, you assign `accounts[i] = NULL;` but you never free the memory that you allocated.

Comment: The reason you're getting garbage for the first card is because you initialize `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`

Comment: @Barmar I prefer using the getchar() loop so i can check if the input is %, then i know it's the final line of input. Also I've had some problems previously when implementing scanf for the ID input. Edit to follow up question: i'm starting from 1 because the first index is already filled from the stage_one call

Comment: Use `scanf()` and then just check if the first character of the word is `%`.

Comment: What have you learned by using your debugger?

Comment: `scanf("%s", str); if (str[0] == '%') { return 0; } else { strcpy(one_card->id, str); }`

Comment: probably the code that calls `stage_two` has not set up the argument properly ... you should post the Minimal Reproducible Example as this will make everything clear

Comment: In stage one, `accounts[0]->id` should be `(*accounts)[0].id`  , which is the same for `0` but not the same for `1` if you in future go on to have more than 1 element in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, thanks to some of the suggestion, while working on the Minimal Reproducible Example it brought to my attention that I completely forgot to realloc additional memory in the main function.